# Module import Error and NameError in Flask using Heroku

Tags: python

I do have this issue when deploying a small app to heroku, the requirements.txt is very minimal, the app crash with `Cannot import module 'NewsApiClient'` when using

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
```

and the app actually start with a 500 Internal Error when using `from newsapi import *`

> NameError: name 'NewsApiClient' is not defined

```
newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='xxxxxxxxxx')
```

What I've done so far is create an empty init file on the root folder

Comment: Can you show your requirements.txt file? It seems that the `newsapi` package was not installed or not installed in the right location.

Comment: @karl https://github.com/usfslk/radar/blob/master/requirements.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are importing the incorrect package in your `requirements.txt` file. You have imported the [newsapi](https://pypi.org/project/newsapi/) package which is different then the [python-newsapi](https://pypi.org/project/newsapi-python/0.2.3/) package.

Changing the `newsapi==0.1.1` to `newsapi-python==0.2.3` should fix your problem with the importing error as long as you reinstall the package dependencies.